# Google drive API and javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Is there any way to download a file with Google Drive ID using Javascript?
I have made a research, but I found languages ​​like Python and PHP.

Comment: Is this what u want https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#node.js ?

Comment: Just get a sharable link and use it in an anchor tag

Comment: @yueyou Yes, it is exactly what I want. Thanks for share

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the document here

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#node.js

Google drive API support Java, Python and Node.js for your purpose. Relavant code with Google drive API v3 is as below

```js
const fileId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M';
const dest = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/photo.jpg');
drive.files.get({
  fileId: fileId,
  alt: 'media'
})
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Done');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error during download', err);
    })
    .pipe(dest);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26540063)

Comment: Thanks Roberto haha. Hope so